# Order in gaussian integer moduli

Tags: elementary-number-theory, complex-numbers, modular-arithmetic, gaussian-integers

Say I want to find the order of an element in $\mathbb Z[i]$ modulo $a+bi.$ If this element is $x+yi,$ I could write $(a+bi)(c+di)+1=(x+yi)^n.$ I noticed that if $y=0,$ we could do this pretty easily by considering the order of $x$ modulo $N(a+bi)=a^2+b^2,$ but for nonreal or nonimaginary elements this seems harder and maybe needs more computation.

How can I calculate the order $n$? Is it entirely algebraic?

Comment: You could start by looking at the group structure of $(\mathbb Z[i]/(a+bi))^\times$.

Comment: To work with Kenta's suggestion you need to know the factorization of $a+bi$. Do you?

Comment: Oh, and the previous comments were about the *multiplicative* order. Based on your approach of trying to find an integer $n$ such that $(x+yi)^n\equiv1\pmod{a+bi}$. But, may be your exercise actually wants the order in the *additive* group $\Bbb{Z}[i]/(a+bi)$ (quotient by a principal ideal)?? Among other things, the additive order always exists and is finite! Whereas the multiplicative order exists only if $\gcd(a+bi,x+yi)=1$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen For this example I'm working with $a+bi$ prime.

Comment: Ok, so you know that $\Bbb{Z}[i]/(a+bi)$ is a field of size $q:=N(a+bi)=p$ or $p^2$ for some rational prime $p$. So the multiplicative group is known to be cyclic of order $q-1$. The order is thus a factor of $q-1$, and every factor is a possibility. If you have the factorization of $q-1$, then you test one prime factor $\ell\mid q-1$ at a time by checking whether raising to power $(q-1)/\ell$ gives $1$ as the remainder. Rinse and repeat. Something more efficient is probably known, and shortcuts are possible.